# Firebase Multi-database rules 'root' value issue

Tags: database, firebase, firebase-security

I'm using Firebase in my app that utilizes the new Multi-database feature. But, while setting up the rules, I noticed one annoying problem: the 'root' variable in the database rules is returning a `RuleDataSnapshot` of the ***primary database*** and not a `RuleDataSnapshot` of the ***secondary database*** the rules are attached to.

This is a huge problem for me because I have a few constant values in the secondary database that I need to reference in the rules. Because I'm planning to use this method to scale up, I don't want to have to try sorting and remapping these constants to the main database.

*Thanks* 
 ***-Nathan***

Comment: You may not get much help here unless you post your rules and more explanation about what you are seeing that indicates the error.  Maybe better to take this to [Firebase Support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/).  I tried to observe the error you describe on my project using the rules simulator in the Firebase console and was not able see the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay! I found out that this was only happening in the simulator. I tested it live and it seemed to work properly. Definitely submitting this as a bug report. Thanks to anyone who started to check into this!